# Can't instantiate an object with id within its constructor

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I would like to instantiate an MposClient Object, which has this interface:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "UICallback.h"
#import "LoginRequest.h"
#import "TransactionRequest.h"
#import "TYMessage.h"


@interface MPosClient : NSThread

/**
 * Default constructor.
 *
 * @param callback a third party application has to implement the UICallback interface and to<BR>
 *                 create it before to create the MPosClient (see UICallback documentation for<BR>
 *                 more information)
 */
- (id)initWithCallback:(id<UICallback>)callback;


- (void)loginWithRequest:(LoginRequest*)request;

@end
```

Unfortunately its implementation is contained within an .a file.
As you can see the constructor method takes an id object.
This is why I created and implemented the following interface:

```
@interface PosMateCallback:NSObject<UICallback>
{
    NSString* currencyAphaCode;
    int currencyNumCode;
    double amount;
}

-(id) initCallback: (NSString*) currencyAlphaCode currencyNumCode:(int) currencyCode amount:(double) amountToPay;

@end

@implementation PosMateCallback
-(id) initCallback: (NSString*) currencyAlphaCode currencyNumCode:(int) currencyCode amount:(double) amountToPay{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        currencyAphaCode = currencyAlphaCode;
        currencyNumCode = currencyCode;
        amount = amountToPay;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)loginEndedWithResponse:(LoginResponse*)response{
    //NSLog(@" %@ ",[response getExtendedResultCode]);
    //TransactionType type = TransactionType.DEBIT;


}

- (NSString*)postUIRequest:(UIRequest*)request{
    //interruptedTransaction = request.getMessage().equals("ABANDON");
    return NULL;
}


- (void)transactionEndedWithResponse:(TransactionResponse*)response{

}


@end
```

So, in my viewController I try to instantiate an MPosClient object like this:

```
id<UICallback> posmateCallback = [[PosMateCallback alloc] initCallback:@"EUR" currencyNumCode: 978 amount:42];

MPosClient *mposClient = [[MPosClient alloc] initWithCallback: *posmateCallback];
```

But I get the following compilation error:

```
Sending 'id<UICallback>' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<UICallback>'
```

I don't understand at all why this happens, what did I go wrong?

Comment: To convince me that this is the actual code, fix the spelling errors.

Comment: And start a habit to start the names of instance variables with an underscore character. Otherwise, your code is confusing to you and to others.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first ios app

Comment: There are so many fundamental issues with this. Firsly why are you casting it to id when you are passing in an instance of UICallBack anyway ? Change it to UICallBack *postMateCallBack = .... Then you can change your parameter type to hyust UICallBack instead of id<UICallBack> ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line:

```
MPosClient *mposClient = [[MPosClient alloc] initWithCallback: *posmateCallback];
```

What is *posmateCallback supposed to mean? It doesn't make any sense. You can't dereference an id.

Comment: When I remove it I have 17 build errors; is it the library's fault? How am I supposed to instantiate it?

Comment: 1. Iron rule: Any errors are _your_ fault. 2. The thing to remove is the * at the beginning of *posmateCallback. posmateCallback is an id. You can't dereference ids.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "UICallback.h"
#import "LoginRequest.h"
#import "TransactionRequest.h"
#import "TYMessage.h"


@interface MPosClient : NSThread

/**
 * Default constructor.
 *
 * @param callback a third party application has to implement the UICallback interface and to<BR>
 *                 create it before to create the MPosClient (see UICallback documentation for<BR>
 *                 more information)
 */
- (id)initWithCallback:(UICallback *)callback;


- (void)loginWithRequest:(LoginRequest*)request;

@end
```

---

```
UICallback *posmateCallback = [[PosMateCallback alloc] initCallback:@"EUR" currencyNumCode: 978 amount:42];

MPosClient *mposClient = [[MPosClient alloc] initWithCallback:posmateCallback];
```

Comment: When I try to change MposClient I get the compilation error 'Expected a type'